# good reference to learn RaphaelJs

Tags: javascript, raphael

I need to do something by Raphael JavaScript Library and I spend 3 hours to find good reference to learn it,but I didn't find any useful thing.

I surf the raphaeljs web site,but It doesn't have tutorial ,It has a only reference of functions.

Is the any good source to learn it on the web?
with special thanks for you attention

Comment: Check on stackoverflow ;) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1571016/raphael-js-tutorial

Comment: agreed. i'm also a raphael beginner and i've found the best information about Raphael here at StackOverflow

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Stack overflow has been an enormous help for learning Raphael, but I found the best documentation was actually in the sample code on raphaeljs.com.  Its notation is so economical that it takes some getting used to but (for instance), the source on one page alone (http://raphaeljs.com/animation.html) got me jump-started.  16 example animations on the page = 16 micro tutorials in the source.